# How to get server time on client side?

Tags: cme

I'm looking for ability to take Tridion Server Time using javascript (I can see "Server Time" in navigation breadcrumbs area). So is there ability to do that in right way?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is really a javascript question and not really an SDL Tridion Question.  If I'm wrong, can you be more specific?

Comment: Maybe you could change the question to something like "How does Tridion CME display the server time?" I would like to use the same value in my own UI extension.

Comment: Also which Tridion version you are running might be useful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in Tridion 2013, you can get the server time from `Tridion.UI.ServerTime.getInstance()` by calling its `getDate()` method. You might need to call the `retrieveServerTime()` method first if you are using it outside of the standard view.

The object might be available in earlier versions too, I haven't checked.